# No validation on submit Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

For some reason, `form.validate_on_submit()` does not return anything.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, DecimalField, validators
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(dict(
    SECRET_KEY="super awesome key"
))

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Product name', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.Length(min=0, max=30)])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return "Mission accomplished!"
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

```html
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add new grocery product</h1>
<p>Provide appropriate product details</p>
<form method="POST" action="/">
   {{ form.csrf_token }}
   {{ render_field(form.name.label) }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The app itself is supposed to gather user input in specific form and insert this via SQLAlchemy into database. Output is supposed to:

1. Return "Mission accomplished!" if validation succeeded
2. Return validation of which field failed and display error msg "This field is required" on the submit.html template

EDIT

Duo some success with the code, I make another edit to the question. It seems that macro isn't displaying error message for appropriate field if the validation fails.

I.E. if Field name is empty, macro should create and display error message ( This Field cannot be empty) by itself.

FINAL EDIT

I managed to find the solution. Submit.html template seems to cause the issue with macro if render_field looks like this:

```
{{ render_field(form.name.label) }}
```

instaed of this:

```
{{ render_field(form.name) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#This might help    
from flask import Flask
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    #from wtform import SubmitField
    from wtforms import StringField, DecimalField, validators,SubmitField
    from flask import render_template

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(dict(
        SECRET_KEY="super awesome key"
    ))

    class MyForm(FlaskForm):
```

## you need to make an edit to your validators like this

```
        name = StringField('Product name', validators = [InputRequired(), , Length(min=0, max=30)])
    #create submit option in your flask form
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")


    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        form = MyForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            return "Mission accomplished!"
        return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I have just edited my topic with additional informations

Comment: Made changes to your validators, it should work now.

Comment: Just fixed the issue with product_type part - validators of InputRequired couldn't be satisfied from the very beginning - user is not actually providing any input, he just picks the right type. Anyway, even though this part has been fixed, I still don't understand why macro isn't displaying the error msg (i.e. name field is over 30 characters) or Quantity is not an int

Comment: I usually code, name = StringField('Product name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=0, max=30)] instead of   name = StringField('Product name', [validators.InputRequired(), validators.Length(min=0, max=30)]) this change might be help.

Comment: I have seen these two options, I made above changes with the validators but since they seem to work in my option the same, that's not the case. I don't understand actually how are they different (that's my first day with Flask though) but great thanks for your contribution ! The issue with the lack of error msg displayed by macro stays.

Comment: You can display message by [validators.Required("Please Enter Your Name.")]